# Revival badge criteria

Tags: support, badges

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55780662/7583953) from 2018, receiving 2 upvotes. My answer was not the first, but the first was by the poster himself. Does my answer qualify for Revival because the first answer to get a score of 2 was posted by OP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no special exception made for the Revival badge when the first answer is by the asker. You still have to be the first answerer meeting the other criteria in order to be eligible.

Since the criteria takes into account answer score, it wouldn't make sense to exclude answers by the asker. They were still rated as useful by the community, and they still count as answers to the question.

The intent of the badge is to encourage reviving of questions that have not yet received quality answers.

I'm...not even really sure why you posted a second answer there. It isn't clear to me what you are adding to the Q&A that wasn't there previously. The observation that floating-point values in Python are, by default, double precision? Sure, I guess that's useful to state explicitly. I would have added it in as part of an edit of the existing answer, rather than a completely separate answer that covered essentially the same ground. But, your choice, I suppose.

Comment: Maybe revival would better represent reviving a question if it was the first accepted answer instead of the first one with 2 upvotes?

Comment: @Alec Not sure about the practicality. Acceptance requires action to be taken by the original asker of the question. In many cases, when you're reviving old questions, the asker might not be around or active anymore. Practically, it makes more sense to tie the badge to something that the community can do themselves: vote.

Comment: Looking at the question, I remember I posted my answer because OP included this text at the end of his question: `Found the solution (see answers) However, I do not understand, why a "double" is the correct type here and not a "float". If someone can elaborate on that and include the solution, I will mark it as the correct answer.`