# Does the "Revival" badge apply to answering my own questions?

Tags: discussion, support, badges

Quote from [the "Revival" badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival):

> Answer more than 30 days after a question was asked as the first answer scoring 2 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Judging by the intro, I guess answering more than 30 days after my own question was asked as the first answer scoring 2 or more gets the badge too?

Comment: Yes, see [Should self-revival be allowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230403)

Comment: @JeanneDark you managed to link the answer seconds before me, touche :)

Comment: There is also this indirect confirmation from 2019 where the OP asks why an asker got the badge upon answering their own question first with a score of 2 or more: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385433/11407695

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64496620/msal-and-oauth-2-0-request-an-authorization-code-programmatically/68265007#68265007) post:

The OP answered his own question a year after the question was posted. He got a score of 2 and got the revival badge.

[image]

This proves that it is possible to get the revival badge on a self-answered question.